# How to switch scanf input to standard terminal input after reading input through input redirection

Tags: c, io, scanf

I need to have my program read several words from a .txt file and store them into an array using the scanf() function. However, I need to accept user input after that also using scanf. How do I ensure that scanf only accepts user input after all the words are read?

I have tried using scanf() and getchar() to accept whitespace at the end of the file in case that is what scanf is reading at the point where I need user input.

```
char w[15][100];
for(int i =0;i<15;i++)
{

    if(scanf("%s", &w[i][0])=1)
    {
        scanf("%s", &w[i][0]);
    }
    getchar();
    printf("Word read\n");
}
 bool validAnswer2=false;
    while(validAnswer2==false) 
    {
        printf("Would you like to play again?\nType \"y\" to play again or \"n\" to exit: ");
        scanf(" %c", &reply);
        getchar();
        if(reply=='y')
        {
            validAnswer2=true;
        }
        else if(reply=='n')
        {
            validAnswer2=true;

        }

    }
```

When the program reaches the point where scanf needs to accepts user input rather than file input, I have designed it to check if the input is a letter and try scanf again if it is not. The program infinitely tries scanf, each time getting invalid input. I am redirecting input by using nameOfFile < words.txt where words.txt is a file with 15 words.

Comment: As asked, the question has no answer. A program doesn't generally redirect its own input - environment (e.g. command shell) that runs the program does that, and your program has no control over that. Instead, write your reading function so it uses `fscanf()` to read from a supplied file. Then set up a driver program that loops over the command line arguments, and opens/reads/closes each one sequentially. All you need to do is define some special string(e.g. `"-"`) that, if supplied on the command line, represents `stdin`.

Comment: How do you expect `if(scanf("%s", &w[i][0])=1) { scanf("%s", &w[i][0]); }` to work? After the first call to `scanf`, the character you want to read is already in `w[i][0]`, when  you then call `scanf` the second time, you are overwriting that with the next character. Also, do you see the conversion mismatch between `"%s"` and `&w[i][0]`?

Comment: A decent walk-through on this point is [Pipes, Forks, & Dups: Understanding Command Execution and Input/Output Data Flow](http://www.rozmichelle.com/pipes-forks-dups/)

Comment: You can read the words from a different FILE *, and read the other input from stdin.

Comment: Why are you doing scanf twice?  By writing `if( scanf(..., &addr) == 1 ) scanf(...,&addr)`, you are skipping every other input.  (eg, the second scanf overwrites the data read by the first).

Comment: Your program has only one input stream, and it knows nothing of concepts like "keyboard", and "user".  If you want input to come first from a file and then from some other stream, then pipe those to your program.  eg `{ cat words.txt; cat; } | nameOfFile`